# Cursor issue with an array of strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, cursor

How can I use this Cursor, and tell me how am I supposed to reach the second value of "queryFields" which is "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER"?

```
 else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT)
    {
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();

        //Specifying which queries you would like to return the value of the contact for.
        String[] queryFields = new String[]
                {
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                };

        //Where?
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, queryFields, null, null, null);

        //Check if you have any result inside
        if(c.getCount() == 0)
        {
            c.close();
            return;
        }

        //Getting the first value from the query. (first column, first row)
        c.moveToFirst();
        do
            {
            String suspect = c.getString(0);
            crime.setmSuspect(suspect);
            suspectButton.setText(suspect);
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());

        String number = c.getString(1);
        crime.setmSuspectNumber(number);
        callSuspectButton.setText(number);

        c.close();
    }
```

Here is the error that I get:

> Invalid column data1